# animationEnd event handler - event heard two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, wow.js

I have a code:

```
$('#sectionName').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

which is meant to trigger the alert when animation of #sectionName ends.

It does its job but it is also triggered first time the website is launched.

Is there a way to prevent it? Some way to trigger this alert only when the animationend event is heard for the second time?

PS I am using wow.js, so the #sectionName object slides in, after scrolling to certain page point, and then I want the alert to be displayed.

Comment: No, the event will be called after all animation ends on the selected element. To get around this you could delay adding this event handler until after the first slide animation has completed.

Comment: But there is only one animation of the #sectionName and that is the "slide in" of this element, yet the alert is triggered when I launch the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it simple:

```
Var firstTime = true
$('#sectionName').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
    if(firstTime){
        firstTime = false;
        return;
    }
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Well, I do not know what to say. It was that simple that I even did not think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wow.js `callback` to catch an animation is started:

```
var sections = ['sectionName', 'sectionName2']
var wow = new WOW({
  callback: function(box) {
    var $box = $(box);
    if ( sections.indexOf( $box.attr('id') ) >= 0 ) {
      $box.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
          alert("Hello");
      });    
    }
  }
}).init();
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/6g01kLsh/ ]

Answer (score 0):

Only tested for `animationend` and `webkitAnimationEnd`.

```js
var isWebkitAnim = window.onanimationend === undefined && window.onwebkitanimationend !== undefined
var animationEndEvent = isWebkitAnim ? 'webkitAnimationEnd' : 'animationend'

$('#sectionName').on(animationEndEvent, function() {
    alert("Hello")
})
```